# How to get speed way of og:image in meta tag from given url using php

Tags: php, zend-framework, feedly

I want to save feed details from feed url.I made this with zend feed reader.But problem i faced is image of feed.Client want it as same as feedly.I think feedly takes from og:image tag  in faster way.

How to i get og:image from meta code fastest way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.whitelotuscorporation.com/images/symbol.png"/>
```